# Is there any way to remove a class after an assembly has build?

Tags: c#, .net, class, build, assemblies

I want to remove a class which is added by an obfuscator in a .NET assembly.

This should be possible (cause the obfuscator added one), but I'm not sure in which way.

Has anyone an idea or did something like that?
Every clue is welcome.

Comment: Now i wonder how could that be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) should be able to help you editing the IL of the assembly and removing the class.